# toggle true false on press of checkbox in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a checkbox in react-native. I want to and uncheck it by a click of a button

Below is my code:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class SignIn extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { tick: false, }
    }

    checkTick() {
        this.setState({ tick: !this.state.tick })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.SignInConfirmation}>
                <CheckBox
                    title='click'
                    checked={this.state.tick}
                    onPress={this.checkTick}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')

I can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { tick: false, };
        this.checkTick = this.checkTick.bind(this)
    } 

try this

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```js
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class SignIn extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    state = { tick: false, }
    checkTick() {
        this.setState({ tick: !this.state.tick })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.SignInConfirmation}>
                <CheckBox
                    title='click'
                    checked={this.state.tick}
                    onPress={this.checkTick}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```